# Creating Azure resources from Net Core web app locks interface

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-functions, azureservicebus

In brief, what is the best way to create `Azure` resources (`VM`'s, `ResourceGroups`, etc) that are defined programmatically, without locking the web app's interface because of the long time that some of these operations take?

More detailed:
I have a `Net Core` web application where customers are added, manually. Once added, it automatically creates some resources for `Azure`. However, I noticed that my interfaces is 'locked' during these operations. What is a relatively simple way of detaching these operations from the web application? I had in mind sending a trigger using a `Service Bus` or `Azure Relay` and triggering an `Azure Function`. However, it seems to me that all these resources return something back, and my web app is waiting for that. I need a 'send and forget method' for that. Just send out the trigger to create these resources, don't bother with the return values for now, and continue with the app.

If a 'send and return' method also works within my web app, that is also fine.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to queue the work to run the background and then return the action immediately. The easiest method of doing this is to create a hosted service. There's a couple of different ways to do this:

1. Use a [queued background service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks) and actually queue the work to be done in your action.
2. Just write the required info to a database table, redis store, etc. and use a [timed service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks) to perform the work on a schedule.

In either case, you may also consider splitting this off into a [worker service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#worker-service-template) (essentially, a separate app composed of just the hosted service, instead of running it in the same instance as your web app). This allows you to scale the service independently and also insulates your web app from problems that service might encounter.

Once you've set up your service and scheduled the work, you just need some way to let the user know when the work is complete. A typical approach is to use SignalR to allow the server to notify the client with progress updates or success notifications. However, you can also just do something simple like email the user when everything is ready.